# I would like to delete some photos from my phone camera roll, that i have imported to my Mac, will they stay on my Mac?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, mac, photos

I recently imported all my photos from my iPhone to my Mac. Now they are on both devices. I would like to delete some of them from my phone camera roll, but i want them to stay on my Mac. Will the photos/videos delete from both devices

Comment: Yes you can delete them. You Mac stores your pictures as a separate file and so does your iPhone.

Comment: As long as you are talking about the "Camera Roll" and not "Photo Stream", then yes, they can be deleted from your phone and will remain on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in short, you are safe.

Depending on what software you are using, the *only* thing that could potentially happen is you delete your photo albums that you have *synced* to your iPhone, which is a manual process or you are syncing photos to your iPhone from your mac. However, since you stated you imported them, I don't foresee any issues.

**NOTE** if you are referencing iCloud, then also, you have nothing to worry about. iCloud stores all the files in your iCloud but if you delete them from different devices it only deletes it from that device, unless you haven't had time to sync it to your Mac, but again, strictly importing, meaning you dragging and dropping or clicking the import to iPhoto/Aperture etc button, than you are good to go.